# using select tag and a href within php and mysql query

Tags: php, html, sql, select, hyperlink

Right now, I have a php code that I want to make select menu with. In select menu are usernames, and I am wanting to add a href value to each of the options. The problem is, that the usernames are a mysql query. The following code doesn't quite work. CORRECTION: It doesn't add the Session user_id, rather it adds the user_id value of the last user_name on the list, regardless of who I chose.

```
<?php

echo "<select>";

$user_list = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, username FROM users");
while($run_user = mysql_fetch_array($user_list)) {
        $user = $run_user['user_id'];
        $username = $run_user['username'];

        echo "<option><a href='index.php?user=$user'>$username<br></a>";    

}

     ?> 
     </option> 
       </select>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem quite right - both variables in the `<select>` are being set purely from the SQL database, so if the database is right, you should be getting different values. What do you mean by it's adding the `user_id`? To the database after your form is submitted?

Comment: @andrewsi Sorry, I quickly figured out that it gives every user_name on the list the same value as the last person in the option menu.

Comment: Also - why do you have an `<option>` tag with an href link in it? I'm not sure that that will work.

Comment: @andrewsi it isn't working. I am trying to figure out how to make each one of the users have a different value. for example, when you select "user1", the hyperlink would read 'index.php?user=1'.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `</option>` tag within the while loop. Although I don't understand why you would want a link within a dropdown or know if its allowed. Maybe you wanted something like: `<option value=$user_id>$username</option>`

Also the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.